# Linq Best way to Set the inner property

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5, entity-relationship

I am trying to pull the results from the database and set the child property while selecting using the Linq (EF V5.0). The reason I am doing this is because there is no relation in the database to use include..

```
 var lamdaResult = from u in model.Entity_Users 
                   join s in model.Entity_Staff on u.UserID equals s.ST_UserID 
                   select new { u, s };
 return lamdaResult.Select(x => x.u.Staff = x.s; return x.u;).FirstOrDefault();
```

I am learning Linq.. the above expression is giving me error.. can someone help me the best way to set the child property...

I could also do this.. but I am wondering is there any better way to fulfill the same result instead of following 2 expressions

```
    var user=null;
    var lamdaResult = from u in model.Entity_Users 
                  join s in model.Entity_Staff on u.UserID equals s.ST_UserID 
                  select new { u, s };
    user = lamdaResult.Select(x => x.u).FirstOrDefault();
    user.Staff = lamdaResult.Select(x => x.s).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: For the first piece of code, I am getting "Invalid expression term ')'"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linq is for *querying*, not for mutating objects.  You'll need to use something other than LINQ to do the mutation, generally a `foreach` is appropriate, although given that you only have a single item, there's no need for even that:

```
var item = (from u in model.Entity_Users 
            join s in model.Entity_Staff on u.UserID equals s.ST_UserID 
            select new { User = u, Staff = s })
           .FirstOrDefault();
item.User.Staff = item.Staff;
return item.User;
```

Comment: Good to know that we cannot alter the child properties with the linq... this is the same way as I did..